# How to Remove Square Taper Chainring Bolts

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, chainring, pedals, bolt

I have removed my chainring from my Bicycle, but I do not know how to remove the chainring bolts I have tried using an Allen key but I cannot move it.

Do I need a special tool?

Here is a photo
[image]

[image]

Any Feedback is Helpful

Comment: Are you sure they're bolts, and not rivets?   The grannie gear is definitely rivetted in place, to my eye.

Comment: The tool is called drill :) It's probably best to check that the the rivets are in standard position for replacement chainring before taking the thing apart.

Answer (score 7):

The rings are not replaceable. You can remove them with a drill if required. This type of chainset is very cheap and quite heavy. It would cost significantly more to replace the rings than to replace the whole chainset! The rings don't look so worn, perhaps you want to change ratios.

If you do buy a new chainset, if it is from a different manufacturer you will probably need a new bottom bracket with the correct spindle length, though not always. Have fun.

Comment: How would I go about drilling them out?